# Ubuntu 20.10 aarch64 (Raspberry Pi CM4) how do I access 1-Wire devices?

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi, arm64

Running Ubuntu 20.10 aarch64 (Raspberry Pi) on a Compute module 4
Am scratching my head on how do I access 1-Wire devices?

I've tested by DS18B20 sensor using Raspberry Pi OS and it works by enabling the device and I can then poll the thermometer in the `/sys/bus/w1/devices/<deviceid>/temperature` .

I've made the same changes to the `/boot/fireware/config.txt`; but, I see no indication that the kernel nor do I see any obvious kernel modules to load that would enable Raspberry pi 1-Wire support.

Anyone know if it's supported and how to access it?

Quick update I've downloaded the linux-kernel and spotted the the drivers for ubuntu are the same in Raspberry PI OS.    e.g. wire, w1-gpio and w1-therm however they are not included in the linux-modules for raspi.

I'm attempting to build raspi kernel and W1 modules to resolve the issue.

I've no idea why they have been excluded from the linux-modules-raspi am assuming its an oversight.   Will update once I have more to tell.

Comment: For Raspberry pi questions, you may want to conside https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ ...

Comment: You mention it working on Raspberry Pi OS, without release details or kernel version (ie. what kernel the module was built for). The raspberry pi info you provided is incomplete thus not very useful for comparison.

Comment: It seems you have created two accounts (possibly accidentally). Would you like them to be merged?

Comment: Thanks Zanna,  I did manage to merge them.. In fact I think I might have a third. ;-)

Comment: So it looks like I'm going to have to dedicate a RPI0-W running Raspberry PI OS for this sensor work.   Seems a shame but I guess the RPI4 I'm running Ubuntu on can act as a power supply until I can find a solution to the W1 driver issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be because 20.10 kernel and modules do not support W1 for Raspberry PI.

I've been investigating the early daily Ubuntu 21.04 image and that does have working support for 1-Wire.

I've imported the modules from 21.05 and its working perfectly on my 20.10 platform.

Answer (score -1):

Running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS with stock kernel 5.4.0 add the line

```
dtoverlay=w1-gpio
```

into your

```
/boot/firmware/usercfg.txt
```

and reboot.

This worked for me, without having to import anything separate.